# How to create list inside list in IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have to create a list of list using split view controller in IPad, i.e, when I select a row in master view a new table  opens in in detail view where i can add list items, I have create d the master list but not able to get the logic to create different lists in detail view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite easy to understand:

- Create a `UIViewController` that will accept some kind of input when created. So when you touch one cell in the master view, you just need to pass some value(s) and then you build the new `UIViewController`.
- You can also check [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1040/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uisplitview-tutorial) tutorial, if you have doubts.

Comment: Its easier and better for you to understand than to just paste some random code. If you were able to successfully create a table in the master view, you can do the same thing in the detail view. Just override your init method (on your master view's UIViewController) and pass the information you need to it.